# android google map services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

i am new in android and i was working on showing a map 
i saw code work on something like it but the problem is the project isn't working on any android version except kitkat 
and it always game me the error message 
when i remove  the "fragment" tag from the layout.xml file no error occurs but of course no map will be displayed 
if i put "com.google.android.gms.maps" instead of "fragment" tag it will be the same problem

and as i said before it work only on kitkat ( i tried it on note 2 and it worked) 
when i made the project  put min version 4.0 so clearly the problem is from 
google play services

so any one can help me with this problem ?please

the layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
 <fragment
 android:id="@+id/map"        
  android:layout_width="match_parent"        
   android:layout_height="match_parent"        
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.streetApp.steertapp4"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.streetApp.StreetApp4.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.streetApp.StreetApp4.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<library />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.streetApp.steertapp4.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCjH-Qv2-8DIYpkm41ciYUAUkmiBmx2BWw" />




 </manifest>
```

Comment: please show us your error log and related code

Comment: i edited the question and i posted the code 
and here is a sample of messages

in log cat i got Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.streetApp/com.streetApp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: you should include `<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCjH-Qv2-8DIYpkm41ciYUAUkmiBmx2BWw" />` before `</application>` and also you should include `com.google.android.gms.version` as meta data. Did you follow the instructions on Google Maps API Android? You'll have no problems at all if you follow it.

Comment: i will put the new problem between the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I think you forgot to add the Google Play Services version you use to your manifest :)

Answer (score 0):

see log cat . they suggest version code like u use 6400012 and excepted version code is 6400035 . So u replace version code with excepted code . another register app with google console, some cases  you seen blank in map . its issue generated by API KEY

Comment: in log cat i got 
Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.streetApp/com.streetApp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: and more that is just a sample

Answer (score 0):

```
//In xml 
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    //    in java file 
        public FragmentManager fManager;
        public GoogleMap googleMap;
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    //declare 
            fManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: // google_play_services_version replace this version code 
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />